# Connectng Users Table to two different Databases for two different Website

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have two Tables

```
**DB1**
users
prices
. . .
```

and

```
**DB2**
users
prices
. . .
```

Both are for a different Website, What I want to do is the make both `users` table a single table, And any user signs-up in one of the two website is signed in the other one too,

What I thought about was making a `DB3` has `users` table, Then linking it with `DB1` and `DB2`, But I really have no idea how to do that nor if this is the only way to make a single users table for two different websites at the same time.

Also I'll be using for example if there is Three Tables Queries needs to be connected with the 3rd Table like this

```
SELECT * FROM users[db3] INNER JOIN prices[db2] WHERE price > 0
```

in case I'm preforming a query of the `db2` website, or

```
SELECT * FROM users[db3] INNER JOIN prices[db1] WHERE price > 0
```

in case it is on `db1` website, How exactly do I do that?

Comment: Are both databases running on the same MySQL server, separate MySQL servers on the same network, separate networks in the same datacenter, or separate datacenters?

Comment: @TheImpaler both databases are running on same server, Also I would like to know if they're both on different Server, How am i supposed to interact with it? With an API?

Comment: The syntax is `db1.users`

Comment: @NevilleKuyt This isn't a join, it should be a union.

Comment: Take a look at the [MERGE storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep a single `users` table on one database, let's say, on DB1.

From database DB2, I would just use:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.users INNER JOIN prices WHERE price > 0;
```

See the prefix `DB1.` there? That way you are accessing a table from a different database.

You need to make sure you grant permissions (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT) on DB1 to the user on DB2.

I would strongly be against keeping multiple copies of the same table. They will easily go out of sync in no time and you'll surely start having all kinds of problems.

Comment: I see, I always thought having the `dot .` part is always meant for aliases, In case the two databases in two different servers, do I use an API?

Comment: The dot is used for separating database, table, and column names.

Comment: Yeah, some databases use a dot for more things. For example, you can use **select * from CATALOG.SCHEMA.TABLE**. And if you have a "federated" database you could even add an extra prefix there: SERVICE.CATALOG.SCHEMA.TABLE.